# Ruby, MongoDB: How to share a Cursor between threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mongodb

The following does not work. The call to resources.next_document within the thread returns nil. The same call without threading works as expected.

Any MongoDB experts out there? :P

```
  resources = db[Resource::COLLECTION].find 

  number_of_threads.times do
    threads << Thread.new do
      while resource = resources.next_document
        puts 'one more doc'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the driver itself is threadsafe, individuals cursor aren't, so you can't reliably process the data in the way you're describing.

One possibility would be to have a single thread that iterates over the documents, handing them off to any number of worker threads for the actual processing.

Comment: Interesting... Why would the query being started before or after Thread spawning affect the Cursor differently if the cursor is shared among all threads?

Comment: kb: have a look at my answer and tell me what you think

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up using:

Feedback welcome

```
pool = DocumentPool.new(db)
5.times do 
  Thread.new do
    while doc = pool.next_document
      #something cool
    end
  end
end


class DocumentPool   
  COLLECTION = 'some_collection'

  def initialize(db)
    @db = db                
    @first_doc = cursor.next_document      
  end

  def collection
    @db[COLLECTION]
  end

  def cursor
    @cursor ||= collection.find
  end   

  def shift
    doc = nil
    if @first_doc
      doc = @first_doc   
      @first_doc = nil  
    else
      doc = cursor.next_document    
    end
    doc
  end                               

  def count
    collection.count
  end
end
```

Comment: This may work in some situations, but I don't believe it's foolproof. For that, you'd need to synchronize around the collection's next_document method.

Comment: Why would the next_document method need to be synchronized but not my own "shift" method wouldn't?

Comment: I'm not sure that this @first_doc stuff makes sense. All that shift has to do is synchronize around the call to next_document.  By the way, in you example code at the top of the example, you call pool.next_document. I think you mean pool.shift.